# If $n = o(u_n)$, show that the asymptotic density of $(u_n)$ is zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $A\subset \Bbb N$, then the asymptotic density of $A$ is defined by the folllowing limit (if it exists):

$$
d(A) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|A \cap \{1, 2, \ldots n\}|}{n}.
$$

Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of $\Bbb N$ strictly increasing such as $n = o(u_n)$. We denote $A = \{u_n|n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Show that $d(A)$ exists and calculate it.

Intuitively, I think that $d(A)=0$, but I can't show it.

Comment: Well if the sequence $\frac{|A\cap\{1,...,n\}|}{n}$ has a limit, it must be $0$, as one of its subsequences is $\frac{n}{u_n} \to 0$.

Comment: I don't understand why it is one of its subsequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given large $n$ ($\geqslant u_1$), choose $k$ such that $u_k \leqslant n < u_{k+1}$. Then $\lvert A\cap \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}\rvert = k$ and

$$\frac{\lvert A \cap \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}\rvert}{n} \leqslant \frac{k}{u_k}\,.$$

The assumption says $\frac{k}{u_k} \to 0$.

Comment: Oh, it was that "simple"! Thank you very much for your answer!